# Migrate Oracle SQL and Sql Server on new Date

Tags: sql-server, oracle, dateadd

I want to make a query which is compatible for Oracle SQL and PL/SQL.
I use the Dateadd function in SqlServer, which is incompatible for Oracle, there you can use ADD_MONTHS.

Sql Server:

```
DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

Oracle

```
to_date(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1),'DD-MON-YYYY'))
```

Is there any ANSI statement to merge these?

Comment: I don't really understand your question here. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I want to replace these statements by something that works on Oracle and on Sql Server

Comment: Think it is not possible. As you see - there are two different functions.

Comment: Then why not just wrap one function in a function that works like the one on the other platform?

Comment: thats my question, what is that function!

Comment: Thats not what I meant. I meant that if DATEADD doesn't exist in Oracle, you can just create a function called DATEADD that will receive the same parameters as the one in SQL Server and use Add_months inside it to supply the result.

Comment: The same query needs to be compiled in Oracle and in Sql Server, no changes. I'm looking for something uniform, which replaces both language specific syntax

Comment: What I suggested does exactly that.

Comment: I think you missed Yaron's point - the idea is that you manually create your own functions that mimic the other database platform's functions, so that you can run the same query on both. If Oracle doesn't know about DATEADD, you have to write it yourself. Persornally, I'd avoid such a solution, as now you've introduced performance overheads on one of the databases. Why can't you have a selection of queries, one for each db platform that you have to support? That way, you get to make the best use of SQL for that platform.

Comment: Can you give an example? I totally don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The 
   `to_date(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1),'DD-MON-YYYY'))`
can  be simplified to `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,1)` as the `add_months` function returns a date datatype, just like the T-SQL `DATEADD`

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can create this function -

```
create or replace function dateadd(date_type varchar2, shift number, date_to_move date) return date is
x date;
begin
if date_type = 'MONTH' then
select to_date(add_months(sysdate,-1),'DD/MM/YYYY')
into x
from dual;
end if;
return x;
end dateadd;
```

and then the following query will work in oracle -

```
select dateadd('month',-1,sysdate)
from dual;
```

Of course then you still need to the same thing for get_date, and you will still have certain differences between both platforms that will probably prevent running the exact same code on Oracle and SQL Server.
All in all, @Boneist solution sounds the fittest to your problem.